# C++: How do I wait on two (or more) children and receive their outputs?

Tags: c++, linux, process, pipe, fork

I would like to execute several child processes and receive results from them. Each of them run complex algorithms which may take a while. The idea is to ensure that none of them takes longer than a specific timeout. Each child process sets up an alarm which kills the process if it takes too long. When a child process is done, it sends its result and exits normally. To receive the results of the computations I have set up pipes to each of the child processes. The parent process calls waitpid on each child successively and then reads the result from its pipe. This works just fine if they stay within the time limit. It also works if the first child is faster than the second child. However, if the first child takes longer than the second child, then the second child has already exited when it's turn to be waited on and its results are no longer in its pipe.

I had assumed that if a child writes its result to the pipe and then exits the pipe should still remain alive and it's buffer should still be full until it is read and then closed by the parent, but that does not seems to be the case. The interesting thing though: Why does it work at all then? The first child writes the pipe, exits and then the parent reads it. It seems that some time must pass for it to fail. But why?

I could try to wait on all children (waitpid with pid=-1) and based on the pid I receive from waitpid read from the right pipe. However, this works only if there are no other children outside of this sandbox. If the process forks more children then I can no longer know which children belong where.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you forced into forking a new process or could you use C++11 threads?

Comment: Maybe you should not wait for your child processes but use `poll` to monitor the pipes of your child processes. Only if they are closed (do this just before the process kills itself) you can reap your zombie childs.
Although this has nothing to do with C++. It is more posix related.

Comment: @walsht: The idea here is to provide something like a sandbox in which the process can run. If the child process is unstable it does not bring the rest down with it. This is why I would rather fork a new process.

Comment: @mkaes: thanks for the hint about using `poll`. This seems like a good way to monitor several child processes at once. I'll give it a try.